# Select and echo single field from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, echo

I'm trying to select and echo a single field.

This is my code when I'm trying it

```
session_start();
$query = "select id from user where username = ".$_SESSION['username'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
$admin_id = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $admin_id['id'];
```

When I run that code, this warning text appears

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ......
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use quotes when you assign values in sql queries .

```
$query = "select id from user where username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
```

Or

```
$query = "select id from user where username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
```

However, it is not a good practice so you better look forward prepared statements to reduce sql injection vulnerability : https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: i still got this warning message
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:\xampp\htdocs\sikeuanganfasilkom\views\admin\content\admin-jurusan\welcome.php on line 8

how should i do?

Comment: @Bangmamat:echo your query and paste it in your phpmyadmin or whatever you have to access database with graphic interface and run it there.Post your $query and select results here.

Comment: @Bangmamat: Your error means that there are no rows to fetch so there are 2 possibilities : 1) Invalid query 2)You have received no data from your database.

Comment: here is screenshot when i print $query -> http://prntscr.com/39io9e
||
and here is $query result on phpmyadmin -> http://prntscr.com/39iodm

Comment: @Bangmamat:So there are no errors,but query was executed,it means, that there are no rows with `username='winda'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "select id from user where username = '$username'";
```